# Hibernate Criteria query Collections contains certain elements

Tags: java, spring, criteria-api

I have some problems with `Criteria`. I have a `Job` class that contains a set of `Skills`.

The problem comes when I want to filter jobs that contain 2 skills, for example, all jobs that contains skill with id 1 and 3.

Now I have this:

```
for (Skill skill : job.getSkills()) {
    ids.add(skill.getId());
}

criteria.createAlias("skills", "skill");
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("skill.id", ids));
```

but it gives me jobs that contain skill 1 or 3, not only those with both skills.
How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

```
criteria.createAlias("Job.skills", "skill");    
Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();   

for (Skill skill : job.getSkills()) {
    and.add(Restrictions.eq("skill.id", skill.getId()));
}
criteria.add(and);
```

I've tried this but the sql is `and (skill1_.ID=? and skill1_.ID=?)` with no results

Comment: Please post Hibernate version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(Skill skill:job.getSkills()){
                    DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Skill.class,"skill");
                    subquery.add(Restrictions.eq("id",skill.getId()));
                    subquery.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
                    subquery.createAlias("jobs", "job");
                    subquery.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("job.id", "Job.id"));
                    criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(subquery));  
                }
```

I managed to solve it.now it works.

Comment: The Skill class has a reference back to the Job class (bidirectional)? Can this solution be adapted to a unidirectional configuration?  I.e., a Job has a collection of Skill, but Skill knows nothing about Job? What is the value of "Job.id" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
criteria.createAlias("skills", "skill");

for(Skill skill:job.getSkills()){
    List<Long> wrappedParameter = new ArrayList<Long>();
    wrappedParameter.add(skill.getId());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("skill.id", wrappedParameter)));
}
```

Comment: same as @Farhang Amary solution. empty list when i select 2 skills for filter

Comment: Restrictions.in(String,Object[]). I've tried with "new Long[]{skill.getId()}" and now the query is "skill1_.ID in (?) and skill1_.ID in (?)".same thing ,empty result

Comment: what do you mean by "new Long[]{skill.getId()}" ?

Comment: Restrictions.in() requires a collection of objects as second parameter so i tried to create a collection with that skill id.

Comment: same behavior..empty result. query: and skill1_.ID in (?) and skill1_.ID in (?)

Answer (score 0):

the result you are getting is expected. you are using `Restrictions.in` you can use `Criterion`

```
List<Criterion> restrictionList;
for(Skill skill :job.getSkills()){
    //ids.add(skill.getId());
    Criterion ctn=Restrictions.eq("skill.id", skill.getId());
    restrictionList.add(ctn);
}

criteria.createAlias("skills", "skill");
for (Criterion crit : restrictionList){
   criteria.add(crit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but this returns me an empty list. query generated for skills is : "and skill1_.ID=? and skill1_.ID=?"